# i want to make a saving top 5 scores system that saves the top 5 scores of a dice game and deletes the previous 2 saved. please and thank you

Tags: python

```
with open('h:\scores.txt', 'a') as f:
    f.write(f"{userr},{p2score}\n")
    f.write(f"{user},{p1score}\n")
```

I understand that this code will save two variables in a separate text document. It will save their user and player 1 and 2 scores. What I'm having trouble with is creating a top-five system where the top-five scores are also saved in the same file. I also need it so that if the game is run again, it will delete the previous two it saved and save the two new ones.

None of my attempts have been substantial.

Comment: Change the `'a'` to `'w'` and the file will be overwritten instead of appended.  Does that do what you're looking for?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to write the last 2 scores AND the top 5 scores in the same file ?

Comment: yeah if possible

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a filled `score.txt` file with 7 lines, the first 2 being the scores of the last game and the next 5 being the ordered 5 best scores, for example:

```
Joe,1
Jane,2
Zia,67
Tao,55
Esteban,45
Mendoza,32
Cornelius,12
```

At some point you'll want to read the file:

```
with open('scores.txt') as f:
    p1, p2, *top5 = f.readlines()
# removing the endlines from the scores
top5 = [score.strip() for score in top5]
```

After a game, you'll have new scores, for example:

```
userr, user = 'player 2', 'player 1'
p2score, p1score = 48, 20
```

You'll need to update the top5; there are many ways to do this; you can add the new score to the top5 list, sort it by descending scores then keep the first 5 entries:

```
new_score1 = f"{user},{p1score}"
new_score2 = f"{userr},{p2score}"
top5 += [new_score1, new_score2]
top5.sort(key = lambda s: -int(s.split(',')[-1]))
top5 = top5[:5]

print(top5)
# ['Zia, 67', 'Tao, 55', 'player 2,48', 'Esteban, 45', 'Mendoza, 32']
```

Finally, update `scores.txt`:

```
with open('scores.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(f"{new_score2}\n")
    f.write(f"{new_score1}\n")
    for score in top5:
        f.write(f"{score}\n")
```

Now all you have to do is place these code snippets at relevant places in your game's code.

Comment: i receive an error saying
user, userr, *top5 = f.readlines()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected at least 2, got 0)

cant get it to go away

Comment: @sbr perhaps a file is named incorrectly, I've tried Swifty's code here, and it works fine. Make sure `scores.txt` is populated.

Comment: Indeed, I tested it before posting the code; don't forget `Assuming you already have a filled score.txt file with 7 lines`